# Code throwing error: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python

It seems to be maybe running when `S` is empty, but it shouldn't because of my first `if` statement.

Error it throws at line 15: can only concatenate `str` (not "NoneType") to `str`.

```
def encipher(S, n):
    """
    Returns a forward shifted string based on the rules of caesar cipher
    Argument S: String to be shifted
    Argument n: number of spaces shifted
    """

    if len(S) > 0:  
        if ord("a")<=ord(S[0])<=ord("z"):   #lowercase letters
            if ord("a") <= ord(S[0])+n <= ord("z"):   #if the shifter letter is in the alphabet range add
                return rot(S[0],n) + encipher(S[1:],n)
            else:                                   #else subtract
                return rot(S[0],(n-26)) + encipher(S[1:],n)
        elif ord("A")<=ord(S[0])<=ord("Z"):   #uppercase letters
            if ord("A") <= ord(S[0])+n <= ord("Z"): #if the shifter letter is in the alphabet range add
                return rot(S[0],(n)) + encipher(S[1:],n)
            else:                               #else subtract
                return rot(S[0],(n-26)) + encipher(S[1:],n) 
        else:
            return S[0] + encipher(S[1:],n)
    else:
        return 
        
def rot(c, n):
    #shifts a character
    if len(c)>0:
        return chr(ord(c)+n)
    else: 
        return
```

Comment: Specifically, what part of "can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str" is confusing you? Why do you think it "weird" that you can't do something like `"foo" + None`?

Comment: You are assuming that `rot` always returns a `str`; it does not.

Comment: Neither does `encipher`.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  You obviously have a `None` value in your concatenation; we expect you to print and trace the offending value.

Comment: Sorry guys.......

Answer (score 3):

You have `None` returns just changing them to string(`""`) does the trick.

```
def encipher(S, n):
    """
    Returns a forward shifted string based on the rules of caesar cipher
    Argument S: String to be shifted
    Argument n: number of spaces shifted
    """

    if len(S) > 0:
        if ord("a") <= ord(S[0]) <= ord("z"):  # lowercase letters
            if ord("a") <= ord(S[0]) + n <= ord("z"):  # if the shifter letter is in the alphabet range add
                return rot(S[0], n) + encipher(S[1:], n)
            else:  # else subtract
                return rot(S[0], (n - 26)) + encipher(S[1:], n)
        elif ord("A") <= ord(S[0]) <= ord("Z"):  # uppercase letters
            if ord("A") <= ord(S[0]) + n <= ord("Z"):  # if the shifter letter is in the alphabet range add
                return rot(S[0], (n)) + encipher(S[1:], n)
            else:  # else subtract
                return rot(S[0], (n - 26)) + encipher(S[1:], n)
        else:
            return S[0] + encipher(S[1:], n)
    else:
        return ""


def rot(c, n):
    # shifts a character
    if len(c) > 0:
        return chr(ord(c) + n)
    else:
        return ""

S = "b"
n = 3
print(encipher(S, n))
```

Output:

```
e
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry my question was formatted poorly

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow :) PS: if it has solved ua problem then please accept.

Answer (score 0):

When  **encipher** reached the last character of your string, it's going to call the function with and empty string **''**

```py
S = 'a'
S[1:]
```

**output:** ''

Which will return a None value as per your code.
please change the return value:

```
return ''
```